# SharePoint 2010: Quickest way to get the number of items in a web application?

Tags: sharepoint

To calculate the number of index partitions you should use for search, you should calculate the number of items you are indexing.  How do you easily calculate the number of items in a SharePoint web application?

Anyone done this?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you are wanting to know? Indexes are column based not item based.

Comment: Brian. I should have said partitions. The recommendation is one partition for 5-10 million items.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[AllDocs]
SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[AllUserData]
```

For each content database.

It won't be exact, but it should get you close to the number.